# angular prepending path to $routeProvider templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I have this route definition:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/accountEdit/:accountId?',
    {
        templateUrl: 'templates/accountEdit.html',
        controller: 'accountEditController' 
    });
```

when the url changes to http://domain.com/accountEdit/24 i get a 404:

GET http://domain.com/accountEdit/templates/accountEdit.html 404 (Not Found)

why is angular prepending accountEdit/ before the templateUrl?

i can access the file ../templates/accountEdit.html in my browser.

this was working, i've obviously changed something but can't see what. the only think i can think of is that i changed RouteConfig in the Web.Api backend to default to "index.html"

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "index.html");
```

but i've undone those changes and i still get the 404.

**update:**

i can workaround this by not using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

i think it is caused by using both html5Mode and routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "index.html");

maybe i need a better way of returning index.html when i access the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) like:

```
angular.module('app', [])
            .config(function ($httpProvider) {
               // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider.
               $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');
            })
            .factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
                      return {
                          // On request success
                          request: function (config) {
                              config.url = 'mypath/'+ config.url
                              console.log(config); 
                              // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
                              return config || $q.when(config);
                          }

                  }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

For you index (site root), you can also do like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/accountEdit/:accountId?',
    {
        templateUrl: 'templates/accountEdit.html',
        controller: 'accountEditController'
    })
    .when('/home',
    {
        templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
        controller: 'indexController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
```

I have mapped the site soot to /home, for example, but you do as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try prepend `templateUrl` value by `/`:

`$routeProvider.when('/accountEdit/:accountId?', { 
   templateUrl: '/templates/accountEdit.html', 
   controller: 'accountEditController'
});`

Comment: That causes further issues as well as the 404.